# How to use clang-10 or gcc-10 when building via Github Actions?

Tags: c++, github-actions, c++20

I'm writing a library in C++ that implements a few different coroutine primitives, and the library is targeted at the newly released C++20. As a result, it also makes use of things like concepts that were added to the language in C++20.

I want to use github actions to build the library, but builds are failing because `ubuntu-latest` uses GCC 9 and CLang 9, but my library requires at least GCC 10 or Clang 10 to build.

I attempted to configure the build action by setting `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-10`, but the action fails in the Configure CMake phase because g++-10 can't be found on the system.

**Is there any way specify github actions should use GCC 10 or Clang 10?**

This is the most recent workflow file I tried running:

```yaml
name: CMake

on: [push]

env:
  # Customize the CMake build type here (Release, Debug, RelWithDebInfo, etc.)
  BUILD_TYPE: Release

jobs:
  build:
    # The CMake configure and build commands are platform agnostic and should work equally
    # well on Windows or Mac.  You can convert this to a matrix build if you need
    # cross-platform coverage.
    # See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/configuring-a-workflow#configuring-a-build-matrix
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Create Build Environment
      # Some projects don't allow in-source building, so create a separate build directory
      # We'll use this as our working directory for all subsequent commands
      run: cmake -E make_directory ${{runner.workspace}}/build

    - name: Configure CMake
      # Use a bash shell so we can use the same syntax for environment variable
      # access regardless of the host operating system
      shell: bash
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/build
      # Note the current convention is to use the -S and -B options here to specify source 
      # and build directories, but this is only available with CMake 3.13 and higher.  
      # The CMake binaries on the Github Actions machines are (as of this writing) 3.12
      run: cmake $GITHUB_WORKSPACE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-10

    - name: Build
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/build
      shell: bash
      # Execute the build.  You can specify a specific target with "--target <NAME>"
      run: cmake --build . --config $BUILD_TYPE

    - name: Test
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/build
      shell: bash
      # Execute tests defined by the CMake configuration.  
      # See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html for more detail
      run: ctest -C $BUILD_TYPE
```

And this is the point where it fails:

```
Run cmake $GITHUB_WORKSPACE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-10
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    g++-10

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/runner/work/conduit/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/runner/work/conduit/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: On a slightly related note, I recommend that you don't settle for only one compiler. Do tests using *both* compilers, as the different implementations could expose different bugs in your code (as well as recognize different possible problems and emit different warnings).

Comment: drescherjm, g++-10 isn't on the PATH for the server that github is using to run Github Actions. They have options for different operating systems / build environments Github Actions can be run on, and I want to know if there is a build environment availible that *does* have g++-10 and clang++ version 10.

Comment: You could always add a step to *install* GCC-10. IIRC it should be available through the standard Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Some programmer dude, adding a step to install gcc 10 would increase the run time of the test from about 5 seconds to several hours. I don't believe I can install it from a repo since I don't have root on their server.

Comment: I don't suggest you build it from *source*, but rather do a normal `apt install g++-10`. And such systems uses *virtualization* to separate your environment, and you usually have root access in the specific container running your commands.

Answer (score 15):

As *Some programmer dude* mentioned, installing g++ from apt is the way to go (unless it's installed by default); adds a minute or two to the build. Then you can tell cmake which compiler it should use by passing `CC` and `CXX` variables during configure step:

```yaml
- run:   |
         sudo apt update
         sudo apt install gcc-10 g++-10
  shell: bash

# ... #

- run:   cmake $GITHUB_WORKSPACE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE
  shell: bash
  env:
   CC:   gcc-10
   CXX:  g++-10
```

Same solution applies when you want to use clang.

Comment: Helpful! Why do we need to add `shell: bash` in this case? I've never seen those before.

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler Oh, that's just me... Back in beta times, bash was only shell which worked on all platforms, so i made a habit of always using it in answers and adding `shell: bash`. Turns out i got so used to it, i added it even when it was pointless, like here :)

Answer (score 3):

You can see what's installed by visiting https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments.

If you're trying this in 2022, [now](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu20/20220123.1/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md) `ubuntu-latest` has "GNU C++ 9.3.0, 10.3.0". `g++` is linked to version 9, but `g++-10` is available on the PATH without any extra installation steps.

Answer (score 2):

I am using both gcc-9 and clang-10 for [C (only) project](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/lzws).

```yaml
- name: Setup dependencies
  if: startsWith(matrix.os, 'ubuntu')
  run: |
    sudo apt-get install -y gcc-9 llvm-10 clang-10
    sudo update-alternatives \
      --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 100 \
      --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ar gcc-ar /usr/bin/gcc-ar-9 \
      --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib gcc-ranlib /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-9 \
      --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-9
    sudo update-alternatives \
      --install /usr/bin/llvm-ar llvm-ar /usr/bin/llvm-ar-10 100 \
      --slave /usr/bin/llvm-ranlib llvm-ranlib /usr/bin/llvm-ranlib-10 \
      --slave /usr/bin/llvm-cov llvm-cov /usr/bin/llvm-cov-10
    sudo update-alternatives \
      --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-10 100
```

PS you need to update more alternatives for C++ project, just example.